# Apache zookeeper connectivity issue in cluster node & does zk use telnet internally?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm not able to connect to zk of other kafka cluster nodes. To debug the issue, have tried connecting to other zk cluster ip on port 2181 with telnet, but have observed that its not able to connect/reach.
i.e.

From ip1 box :

```
telnet <ip2> 2181
```

is not working/reachable.

whereas, if i try to telnet to same box ip for port 2181 its working fine & is connected.
i.e.

From IP1 box, telnet  2181 is working fine.

How can i debug this issue & check the root cause?
Also, please confirm if confluent zk uses telnet internally for connectivity to zk cluster ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "Confluent ZK".

Zookeeper does not use Telnet to verify connectivity between nodes. It has its own protocols, which are at the JVM level, using Java TCP Sockets.